# Elastic search snapshot restore another cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, snapshot, elasticsearch-plugin

How to restore elastic search snapshot another cluster? without repository-s3, repository-hdfs, repository-azure, repository-gcs.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is wrt Elastic Search `7.14`. So, it is possible to host a snapshot repository on a NFS. Since, you would like to restore snapshot of one cluster to another, you would need to meet the following pre-requisites:

1. The NFS should be accessible from both source and destination cluster.
2. The version of the source and destination cluster should be the same. At most, the destination cluster can be 1 major version higher than the source cluster. Eg: you can restore a 5.x snaphot. to a 6.x cluster, but not a 7.x cluster.
3. Ensure that the shared NFS directory is owned by uid:gid = 1000:0 (`elasticsearch` user), and appropriate permissions are given (`chmod -R 777 <appropriate NFS directory>` as `elasticsearch` user)

Now, I am detailing the steps that you could take to copy the data.

1. Create a registry of type `fs` on the source cluster:

> ```
> PUT http://10.29.61.189:9200/_snapshot/registry1
> {
>     "type": "fs",
>     "settings": {
>         "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/snapshotrepo",
>         "compress": true
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Take a snapshot on the created registry:

> ```
> PUT http://10.29.61.189:9200/_snapshot/registry1/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
>     {
>       "indices": "employee,manager",
>       "ignore_unavailable": true,
>       "include_global_state": false,
>       "metadata": {
>         "taken_by": "binita",
>         "taken_because": "test snapshot restore"
>       }
>     }
> ```

3. Create a registry of type `url` on the destination cluster. Type `url` will ensure that the same registry (in terms of the shared NFS path) will be read-only wrt the destination cluster. Destination cluster can only restore/read snapshot info, but can not write snapshots.

> PUT http://10.29.59.165:9200/_snapshot/registry1
>
> ```
> {
>   "type": "url",
>   "settings": {
>     "url": "file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/snapshotrepo"
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Restore the snapshot generated from source cluster (in step no 2) to the destination cluster.

> POST http://10.29.59.165:9200/_snapshot/registry1/snapshot_1/_restore

For more info, refer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.it work fine.please read carefully and do.
if you have question contact me waruna94kithruwan@gmail.com.

I have two elastic search cluster.i want a migrate elastic_01 data to elastic_02.
i mean elastic_01 snapshot restore to elastic_02.let's go.

Importent

- verify elastic_01 and elastic_02 has this folder "/home/snapshot/".
- if not exist create this folder first.
- set correct permission to this folder.
- please verify elastic_01 and elatic_02 versions same or match.
- [elasticsearch snapshot documentation]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

(01) set elastic_01 snapshot settings

$ curl -XPUT '/_snapshot/first_backup' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
 "type": "fs",
 "settings": {
    "location": "/home/snapshot/",
    "compress": true
 }
}'

(2) add snapshot location to elasticsearch.yml (elastic_01)
    edit elasticsearch.yml file and add this code line and save.

$ path.repo: ["/home/snapshot/"]

(03) create snapshot (elastic_01)

$ curl -XPUT "/_snapshot/first_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true"

(04) set elastic_02 snapshot settings

$ curl -XPUT '/_snapshot/first_backup' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
 "type": "fs",
 "settings": {
    "location": "/home/snapshot/",
    "compress": true
 }
}'

(05) add snapshot location to elasticsearch.yml (elastic_02)
    edit elasticsearch.yml file and add this code line and save.

$ path.repo: ["/home/snapshot/"]

(06) create snapshot (elastic_02)

$ curl -XPUT "/_snapshot/first_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true"

(07) copy elastic_01 snapshot to >>>> elastic_02

- delete elastic_02 snapshot folder content     $ rm -rf /home/snapshot/*
- copy elastic_01 snapshot folder content to elastic_02 snapshot folder

(08) list snapshot

$ curl -XGET '/_snapshot/first_backup/_all?pretty'

- it will show backup indexes and snapshot related data

(09) restore elastic search snapshot

$ curl -XPOST "/_snapshot/first_backup/snapshot_1/_restore?wait_for_completion=true"

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: We need to make parameter "include_global_state" to "true"   to restore the template as per link " [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/option_include_gs.html"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/option_include_gs.html%22)

curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"include_global_state": true
}
'

{
"accepted" : true
}

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is to first create a snapshot on nodeB, then delete its data and overwrite nodeA's data to this location?

But according to elastic's documentation, nodeB should mount the NFS directory in a read-only manner, so it does not have write permissions, such as using the type: url repository.

```
PUT _snapshot/local
{
  "type": "url",
  "settings": {
    "url": "file:/home/esdata/snapshot"
  }
}
```